# Geometry problem when finding CDF

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions

A square with side 1 is given, and a point $T$ is chosen randomly inside of a square. Let $Z$ be a random variable that represents distance from point T to some fixed vertex of square.

Let's say we are working with vertex A. I have to find $F_Z(t)$. Obviously when $t\leq 0$ then $F_Z(t)=0$, and when $t>\sqrt2$ $F_Z(t)=1$.

The part when $t\in(0,1]$ I understood.

[image]

Now when $t\in(1,\sqrt2]$, I don't understand. I can't see how they computed the area of the $ABEFD$ section?

[image]

Also, is there any other way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Each of the triangles $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ADF$ have area $\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{2}$, and the wedge $AEF$ is a portion of a disc with radius $AE = t$, which therefore has area $\frac{t^2}{2}$ times the angular extent of $EF$ in radians.  The quantity in parentheses is that angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area of the right $\triangle ABE$ is $\frac{1}{2}(1)(\sqrt{t^2-1})$ because the base is of length $1$ and the hypotenuse is of length $t$.

By symmetry, the area of right $\triangle ADF$ is the same. So adding the two together, we get the first term $\sqrt{t^2-1}$.

Now we address the sector part. Area of a sector is $\frac{1}{2}r^2 \theta$, where $r$ is the radius and $\theta$ is the central angle. In this case $r=t$. So we need to compute the central angle.

Let us get back to the $\triangle ABE$. Say the $\angle BAE =\beta$. Then
$$\tan \beta =\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{1} \implies \beta =\arctan(\sqrt{t^2-1}).$$
By symmetry $\angle FAD= \beta$ as well. Thus 
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-2 \beta=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan(\sqrt{t^2-1}).$$
This implies the are of the sector is
$$\frac{1}{2}t^2 \, \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arctan(\sqrt{t^2-1})\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have annotated your diagram with relevant labels.  The distance $AE$ equals $t$, $AB = 1$, and let $\angle EAB = \theta$.  Then by the Pythagorean Theorem, $$AB^2 + EB^2 = AE^2,$$ so $$EB = \sqrt{t^2 - 1}.$$  We have $$\tan \theta = \frac{EB}{AB} = \sqrt{t^2 - 1},$$ hence $$\theta = \tan^{-1} \sqrt{t^2 - 1}.$$  From this, it is easy to compute the desired area.  $$\triangle AEB \cong \triangle AFD$$ implies the sum of the light gray shaded regions is simply $$EB \cdot AB = \sqrt{t^2 - 1},$$ and the area of sector $FAE$ is given by $$\frac{1}{2} AE^2 \cdot \angle FAE = \frac{1}{2} t^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\theta\right) = \frac{t^2}{2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \tan^{-1} \sqrt{t^2 - 1} \right).$$

My personal preference would have been to write $$\theta = \sec^{-1} t$$ avoiding the square root but it is not of any consequence, being a stylistic choice.